# GetListItems is throwing exception for a combination of viewFields

Tags: sharepoint

I am calling GetListItems webservice to get the data from a sharepoint 2010 server. The Webservice is working fine when I do not provide any value for the ViewField argument or when I call the webservice of individual fields in the list.

But for certain combinations of fields the webservice is throwing exception. Following is the content of exception.

Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:

Any idea what could be the reason for this exception. The surprising thing is that individual field values are not creating any problem but some combination is.

I have been working with SharePoint Webservices from last 6 year but not seen such issue.

Comment: Can you post an example list definition and a combination that does not work for you so we can try to reproduce?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot as I am working on a Customer Server which has confidential data. But I analysed more than 10 combinations of  different fields which are throwing exception but there is no common field among all the combination. I am clueless how to solve the issue :-(